# Are you sure want to delete?

Tags: javascript, php, html, laravel

I have on my delete function a message for confirmation of delete when i put ok nothing is done

**Function from controller**

```
public function destroy($id)
{

    $client =client::find($id);
    $client->delete();
    return redirect('client');
}
```

**view client**

```
<form action="{{url ('client/'.$client->id)}}" method="post">
                            {{csrf_field()}}
                            {{method_field('DELETE')}}
                            <a href="{{url('client/'.$client->id.'/show')}}" 
 class="btn btn-default btn-sm">Details</a>
                            <a href="{{url('client/'.$client->id.'/edit')}}" 
 class="btn btn-primary btn-sm">Editer</a>
                              <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete"
                           href="javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure want to 
 delete?')) $('#frm_{{$client->id}}').submit()">
                            Supprimer
                        </a>
                        </form>
```

[image]

Comment: where is the code which you have write for ok and cancel pop-up ? Ohk button not working is not a question. Is cancel button working ?

Comment: try $(this).parents('form').submit() instead of $('#frm_{{$client->id}}').submit()

Comment: @Vindhyachal Kumar no message no action when i click on delete

Answer (score 1, accepted):

in your route file just change like this

```
Route::get('/client/{id}/delete', 'ClientController@destroy');
```

in your view

```
<a href="{{url ('client/'.$client->id.'/delete')}}" onclick="return confirm('Are you sure?')">Delete</a>
```

Comment: @chagou2704 i guess you dont have jquey function is it ??

Answer (score 0):

`$('#frm_{{$client->id}}').submit()` is a jQuery code, are you sure your page have jQuery properly loaded?

Better use plain javascript: `document.getElementById("myForm").submit()`

Comment: how can i use your answer

Comment: simply replace the button you have to the following:

`<a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete"
                           href="javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure want to 
 delete?')) document.getElementById('frm_{{$client->id}}').submit()">`

Comment: Oh, I just noticed that you doesn't specified the ID to the form?

in the form tag add `id="frm_{{$client->id}}"`

Comment: the same think nothink is change

Comment: paste your modified code either to the initial text or external sources like [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to look at.

Comment: <a class="btn btn-danger btn-sm" title="Delete" href="javascript:if(confirm('Are you sure want to delete?')) document.getElementById('frm_{{$client->id}}').submit()">                                Supprimer
                            </a>

Comment: as I mentioned above, did you added the ID to the <form> tag? otherwise it's just nothing to target..

Answer (score 0):

i think you forget to add id attribute for you form

```
<form action="{{url ('client/'.$client->id)}}" id="frm_{{$client->id}}" method="DELETE">
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done easily by:

```
<a onclick="if(confirm('Are you sure you want to delete this item?')){ deleteFunction() };">Delete</a>
```

Comment: what is deleteFunction()?

Comment: the js function that manage the delete process (e.g. it could call via ajax a code-behind function that delete data from the database)

Comment: if it's a js function, why there is a url_to_delete? Doesn't this function handle the request already? And, most important, how this answer is intended to be helpful? What it is about? confirm() function?

Comment: right the href is redundant, I deleted it.
with this answer you can have in just one line a confirmation, if the user confirms the deleteFunction is called